# Why do I have Apple Developer tools in /private/var/folders? Can it be removed?

Tags: filesystem, disk-space

Some time ago I went through cleaning of my mac and I have removed old developer tools from Library, which were for old iOS versions. I no longer need them, nobody uses them, I have removed them and reclaimed some space.

Today, however, I cam across the `com.apple.DeveloperTools` located in `/private/var/folders`. It's around 40GB of uselessness.

How come it ended up there? Can I safely remove it?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: @patrix this is a very specific question, not general like in the question you linked.

Comment: You asked whether it can be safely removed. Yes it can, that's what the linked post is about. Otherwise, please edit your question to make it clear why your question is *not* a duplicate. Just saying "it isn't" is not enough.